# Bloquear formulario al presionar bóton en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo que lograr que una vez completados los campos, al presionar en "crear encuesta", ademas de crearse la encuesta en la base de datos (que ya lo hace), todo el formulario quede inhabilitado. Este es un componente React. Lo intente con disable:true/false pero no me funciona. ¿como puedo lograrlo?

```
export function CreateForm() { 
  const {
    form, 
    error, 
    handleForm, 
    selectTypeQuestion, 
    addQuestion, 
    deleteQuestion, 
    createSurvey, 
  } = useContext(FormContext); 

  return (
  <section >
      <header>Creación de encuesta</header>
      <form>
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder="Título"
            name="name" 
            id="title"
            value={form.name}
            onChange={handleForm}
          />
        </div>
        {error.name ? <div>{error.name}</div> : null}
        <div >
          <input
            placeholder="Descripción"
            name="description"
            id="description"
            value={form.description}
            onChange={handleForm}
          />
        </div>
        {error.description ? (
          <div>{error.description}</div>
        ) : null}
        {form.questions.map(
          (element, index) =>
            element !== null && (
              <div key={index}>
                <div>
                  {element === null ? null : (
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <select
                            id={index}
                            name="question_type"
                            onChange={selectTypeQuestion}
                          >
              <option value="">Seleccioná el tipo pregunta</option>
              <option value="multiple">Multiple choice</option>
              <option value="simple">Selección simple</option>
              <option value="text">Texto</option>
                          </select>
                          <br />
                          <input
                            placeholder="Pregunta"
                            name="text"
                            id={index}
                            value={element.text}
                            onChange={selectTypeQuestion}
                          />
                          <Question
                            type={element.question_type}
                            index={index}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <button
                  name={index}
                  onClick={() => deleteQuestion(index)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  <IconContext.Provider
                    value={{ style: { fontSize: "1.5rem", color: "red" } }}
                  >
                    <AiFillDelete />
                  </IconContext.Provider>
                </button>
              </div>
            )
        )}

        <button onClick={addQuestion}>
          <IconContext.Provider
            value={{
              style: { fontSize: "1rem", color: "#a72ba0", marginRight: "5px" },
            }}
          >
            <BsPlusCircleFill /> 
          </IconContext.Provider>{" "}
          Añadir pregunta
        </button>
        {error.question ? (
          <div>{error.question}</div>
        ) : null}
        {error.option ? (
          <div>{error.option}</div>
        ) : null}

        <div>
          <button onClick={createSurvey}> 
            Crear encuesta
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}

export default CreateForm;
```

La idea es deshabilitar toda opción de este componente, poniendo en gris o bloqueando todas sus funciones, como el campo titulo, el campo descripción, el botón para agregar preguntas, el botón para crear encuesta, para eliminar preguntas y todo el contenido.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor comparte todo el código de tu componente. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example] para que podamos entender qué es lo que necesitas exactamente. Hay varias maneras de desabilitar un formulario. Pero debes agregar el código de todo tu componente

Comment: Agregado! muchas gracias!